# some tr with border and some without border css bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border

I am creating a web app in which i have a table with multiple `<tr>` and `<td>`

I have taken these bootstrap class `table table-responsive table-bordered` in my div and here is how my table looks:

```html
<div class="table table-responsive table-bordered" style="background-color:white">
                <table id="table" class="table table-bordered font" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <tr ng-repeat="name in tnameandadd" style="border:none;">
                        <td style="font-size:32px; font-weight:bolder;" colspan="6"></td>
                        <td style="font-size:32px; font-weight:bolder; text-align:right;" colspan="3">{{name.empname}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="add in tnameandadd" style="border:none;">
                        <td style="font-size:32px;" colspan="3"></td>
                        <td style="font-size:20px; text-align: right;" colspan="6">{{add.address}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="9" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="9" style="margin-bottom:10px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr class="bg-primary border_bottom" style="padding-bottom: 1em;">
                            <th>SonVin Id</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Brand Name</th>
                            <th>Venue Name</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Area</th>
                            <th>Instructore</th>
                            <th>Training no.</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="rfdata in tableindiv2">
                            <td>{{rfdata.sonvinid}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.date}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.brandname}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.venuename}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.location}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.area}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.instructore}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.trainingno}}</td>
                            <td>{{rfdata.amount}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="9"><div style="margin-top:15px;"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">
                            </td>
                            <td>Total</td>
                            <td>{{totalAmount}}</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

This is my table

I have multiple `tr`-s in my table but I don't want to border some of `tr`-s of the table, and I want to use bootstrap here too, like follow:

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in tnameandadd" style="border:none;">
    <td style="font-size:32px; font-weight:bolder;" colspan="6"></td>
    <td style="font-size:32px; font-weight:bolder; text-align:right;" colspan="3">{{name.empname}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="add in tnameandadd" style="border:none;">
   <td style="font-size:32px;" colspan="3"></td>
   <td style="font-size:20px; text-align: right;" colspan="6">{{add.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

I don't want to border these two `tr`-s.

What I can do here to resolve the issue?

I want to remove border from some of  `tr`-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply `border: none` for `td`, not for 'tr'. So the solution for both `tr`-s is CSS-rule (but do not forget to remove `style="border:none;"` from `tr` markup):

```css
tr[ng-repeat*="in tnameandadd"] td{
    border: none !important;
}
```

Or if these `tr`-s are always first two rows in the table:

```css
#table tr:first-child td,
#table tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border: none !important;
}
```